# Problem in reading text from the file using FileInputStream in Java

Tags: java, inputstream, fileinputstream

I have a file input.txt in my system and I want to read data from that file using FileInputStream in Java. There is no error in the code, but still it does not work. It does not display the output. Here is the code, any one help me out kindly.

```
package com.company;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here

        byte[] array = new byte[100];

        try {
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream("input.txt");

            System.out.println("Available bytes in the file: " + input.available());

            // Read byte from the input stream
            input.read(array);
            System.out.println("Data read from the file: ");

            // Convert byte array into string
            String data = new String(array);
            System.out.println(data);

            // Close the input stream
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `e.printStackTrace();` instead of `getStackTrace()` to find out more about the problem.

Comment: @AndyTurner, he said he didn't get an error though, but it's still good advice.

Where have you put your file? I suspect that the file isn't found and that's why you don't get any output.

Comment: @ErikKarlstrand but is that because he didn't get an error, or because `e.getStackTrace();` will hide the error?

Comment: yes it says input.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Right, there's your problem: `input.txt` isn't in the current working directory when you run the program.

Comment: how to fix this?

Comment: Put `input.txt` in the current working directory when you run the program, or run the program from the directory which contains `input.txt` already.

Comment: You either specify the full path of the file or you put it in your working directory, which is probably `src/main/java/resources`

Comment: As an aside, the `available()` method of an input stream is not intended to be used this way. It doesn't tell you the total size of something, it just tells you what is available without blocking for data.

Answer (score 2):

Use utility class [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readString(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.charset.Charset)).

```
    Path path = Paths.get("input.txt");
    try {
        String data = Files.readString(path, Charset.defaultCharset());
        System.out.println(data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For binary data, non-text, one should use `Files.readAllBytes`.

- `available()` is not the file length, just the number of bytes alread buffered by the system; reading more will block while physically reading the disk device.
- `String.getBytes(Charset)` and `new String(byte[], Charset)` explicitly specify the charset of the actual bytes. `String` will then keep the text in Unicode, so it may combine all scripts of the world.

  *Java was designed with text as Unicode, due to the situation then with C and C++. So in a String you can mix Arabic, Greek, Chinese and math symbols. For that **binary data** (`byte[], InputStream, OutputStream`) must be given the encoding, Charset, the bytes are in, and then a conversion to Unicode happens for **text** (`String, char, Reader, Writer`).*
- [`FileInputStream.read(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D)) requires using the result and just reads one single buffer, must be repeated.

Comment: *`String` will then keep the text in Unicode, so it may combine all scripts of the world.* Maybe some clarification on this…?

Comment: @g00se yes that was a bit thin. Added more text.